# java.util.logging, ResourceBundles, SAAJ: exception on loading Glassfish OSGi webapp bundle

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi, java.util.logging, saaj

I'm being driven out of my mind by the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings != com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:357)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.java:41)
```

It's occurring when I try to deploy a WAB (web application OSGi bundle) to Glassfish (3.1.1).

I'm trying to use an up-to-date version of SAAJ (`com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj...`) rather than the old JDK one (which is the `com.sun.xml.internal.saaj...` one), by putting the string `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl` in the file `META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory`.

It appears there is some logging going on before the OSGi classloading kicks in, and therefore the 'wrong' `ResourceBundle` is being returned during initialization of the static `log` field of `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl` (SAAJ's implementation of `javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory`).

Anyone seen this / any workarounds on offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got to the bottom of this, but manifest voodoo eventually made it go away (with all of the `javax.xml.ws` / `javax.ws.rs` packages in `Import-Package` rather than on the bundle classpath `WEB-INF/lib`).

It was also possible to work around it by using

```
-Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl
```

on Glassfish startup, though obviously this forces that implementation on all users of `MessageFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

See: [JDK-6741342 : Logger.getLogger() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on saaj classes](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6741342).

> Instead, it's related to the introduction of saaj into JDK 6.....and the workaround involved re-ordering jars.